# Numerically solving the equation of motion for inflation in cosmology

Tags: python, ode, computational-physics

I want to solve the equation of inflation involving a scalar field numerically using Python libraries such as `odeint` or `scipy`. The equation is:

$$φ''(t) + 3Hφ′(t) + V′(φ(t))=0\, ,$$

with given condition: $3Mp2H2 = V(φ)$.

Can anyone help me with the code and advice on how to progress on this?

Comment: As soon as you convert your 2nd order ODE into a system of two1st order ODEs you should be able to use any standard ODE package in Python.

Comment: I have edited your question, please check the condition since I didn't know how should it be typed.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Can you tell me how to do this exactly? How do I convert this equation into a system of two 1st order ODEs?

Answer (score 1):

Use $\psi = \phi'$, that's one 1st order ODE; the second one is
$\psi' + 3H\psi + V′(φ)=0\,$

Answer (score 1):

From what I come to understand about the equation of cosmological inflation, you actually do not know the Hubble constant $H$, but in fact $H$ is a function of $\varphi$. More precisely, the equation is
$$\frac{d^2 \varphi}{dt^2} \, + \, 3H\, \frac{d \varphi}{dt}  \, + \, V'(\varphi) \, = \, 0$$
where
$$H^2 \, = \, \frac{1}{3M_p^2}\, \left(\, \frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\Big)^2 \, + \, V(\varphi)\,\right)$$
Furthermore, $V(\varphi) \, =\, \frac{1}{2} M_p^2 \, \varphi^2 $ so more precisely,
$$\frac{d^2 \varphi}{dt^2} \, + \, 3H\, \frac{d \varphi}{dt}\, + \, M_p^2\,  \varphi \, = \, 0$$
where
$$H \, = \, \sqrt{\frac{1}{6M_p^2}\, \left(\,\Big(\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\Big)^2 \, + \, M_p^2 \, \varphi^2\,\right) }$$
Thus, finally, the actual equation is
$$\frac{d^2 \varphi}{dt^2} \, + \,3\sqrt{\frac{1}{6M_p^2}\, \left(\,\Big(\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\Big)^2 \, + \, M_p^2 \, \varphi^2\,\right) } \, \frac{d \varphi}{dt}\, + \, M_p^2\,  \varphi \, = \, 0$$

You can express it a system of two first order differential equations for the two unknown function $\varphi = \varphi(t)$ and $w = w(t)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
&\frac{d\varphi}{dt} \,=\, w \\
&\\
&\frac{dw}{dt} \,=\, -  \,  \, M_p^2\,  \varphi  \, - \,3\, \sqrt{\frac{1}{6M_p^2}\, \left(\, M_p^2 \, \varphi^2 \, + \, w^2 \,\right)} \, w  
\end{align}

When I wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def H(phi, dphi_dt):
  return np.sqrt( (M*phi)**2 + dphi_dt**2) / (M*np.sqrt(6))

# pointwaise calculation for the solve_ivp solver
def f(t, y):
  return np.array([ y[1],  - (M**2)*y[0] - 3*H(y[0], y[1])*y[1] ])

# simultanous matrix calulcation on a grid for phase portrain 
def F(phi, dphi_dt):
  return dphi_dt, - (M**2)*phi - 3*H(phi, dphi_dt)*dphi_dt

r1 = 5.0
r2 = 5.0
resolution1 = 30
resolution2 = 30
Phi, dPhi_dt  = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-r1, r1, resolution1), np.linspace(-r2, r2, resolution2))

# to draw a phase portrait of the dynamics of the ODE system 
M = 2
U , V = F(Phi, dPhi_dt) 

plt.streamplot(Phi, dPhi_dt, U, V)
plt.axis('square')
plt.axis([-r1, r1, -r2, r2])
plt.show()

# to find a specific solution
# initial conditions
phi0 = - 5
dphi0_dt = 5 
y0 = np.array([phi0, dphi0_dt])
start_time = 0.
stop_time = 12 

time = np.linspace(start_time, stop_time, 150)

# numerical integrator
sol = solve_ivp(f, [start_time, stop_time], y0, method='Radau', t_eval=time)

# plot of the solutions ( phi(t), dphi_dt(t) ) in the phase plane
plt.plot(sol.y[0,:], sol.y[1,:])
plt.plot(sol.y[0,-1], sol.y[1,-1], 'ro')
plt.plot(sol.y[0,0], sol.y[1,0], 'yo')
axx = plt.gca()
axx.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

# plot of the graph of the solution (t, phi(t) ) in the t, phi plane
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0,:])
plt.plot(sol.t[-1], sol.y[0,-1], 'ro')
plt.plot(sol.t[ 0], sol.y[0, 0], 'yo')
axx = plt.gca()
axx.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

I got the following plots:

phase portrait of various trajectories in the phase plane $( \varphi, w)$:

[image]

one specific solution $( \varphi(t), \, w(t) )$, shown in the phase plane $( \varphi, w)$

[image]

the graph $(t, \, \varphi(t) )$ of the same solution in the plane $(t, \, \varphi)$:
[image]